# Customizing Waypoint/Viapoint Pushpins and Labels in Bing Maps V8

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm currently migrating an application from V7 to V8 and what I had done in the was to hide the waypoints and viapoints. I just used custom icon pushpins to mark start/end/via points on the route.

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: bingMapCredentials,
    showDashboard: false
});

var directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
// Specify handlers for the 2 possible outcomes of the route calculation
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsError', displayError);
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', processSuccess);

directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
    waypointPushpinOptions: { visible: false },
    viapointPushpinOptions: { visible: false },
    autoUpdateMapView: false
});
```

I can't find the waypointPushpinOptions or viapointPushpinOptions in the [documentation for setRenderOptions(DirectionsRenderOptions Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt750365.aspx). Is there a way to hide the waypointPushpins or viapointPushpins?

There is also text being displayed with the longitude and latitude of the waypoint/viapoint beside the pushpins. Is there a way to hide this text as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can't find these in the documentation as they are not currently supported. customization of the route style has only just been added to the experimental branch of V8. The following options can be used to customize the route rendering: waypointPushpinOptions, firstWaypointPushpinOptions, lastWaypointPushpinOptions, drivingPolylineOptions, walkingPolylineOptions, transitPolylineOptions